# The art of accepting the correct answer

Tags: discussion

I can't figure out, how should the person who asked a question "what is the correct way to .." or "What does X mean?" decide, which of the answers to accept? This person doesn't know the answer. The suggested answers cannot be proven correct, as it is in programming, where the correct code is the code that works.

Does it mean that the authors of the questions have to choose the most convincing answer? And is it always the case that the most convincing answer is the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

A good hint is given by the community feedback: upvotes. That certainly makes you understand what is correct from what is not.

Note that the OP does not only accept "the correct answer" but also the most helpful for that situation.

Even in the event that the OP accepts the wrong answer, which I've seen quite rarely honestly, the upvotes will still tell the future visitors what to trust and what not.

Comment: Aren't "upvoted" a synonym for "convincing"?

Comment: Shouldn't we be more careful in explaining to people when to upvote an answer?

Comment: @Olga I don't see any problem with upvoting... Why do you think we need to explain it?

Comment: I'm afraid that upvoting is equivalent to saying "I like the answer". But it doesn't imply that the answer is correct, it might just be witty, or very detailed, or it may say that the upvoter intuitively believes to be true.

Comment: On the other hand, it would be bad to ask people make sure that the answer that they upvote is actually correct. So, I don't know what to do =)

Comment: @Olga The upvote can mean many things. I upvote for many reasons: research, correctness, I like the answer, etc...

Comment: @Olga In most cases I wouldn't upvote an answer if it's factually wrong (at least to my knowledge).  On the other hand, if the answer shows research and/or drives in the right direction (yet slightly off), I might still upvote it and leave a comment explaining my disagreements.

Comment: @AleksG I also tend to do something of this kind. But when accepting an answer, I feel a somewhat greater responsibility. I feel that I should actually verify each answer that seems correct and only accept it if I also come to the opinion that it is the correct answer. For me, it takes a lot of effort to accept an answer =) and it often leads to discussions in comments, too, because I find something that I disagree with, and I don't know anymore whether I should accept the original answer, or correct it :(

Comment: @Olga I totally feel the same! Don't worry, you're not alone. Remember that **you're not required to accept an answer right away**, take as much time as you want (not years though lol)... No, seriously, if you have some doubts, leave that question alone, leaving or not a comment before doing that explaining your concerns. Someone else might come up with a better answer or someone will fix the existing one. Either way you do have that responsibility, so don't take the acceptance too lightly, which you are already doing. :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer mark is also just a hint. (The same way as Alenanno calls upvotes a hint). To me "the maximum upvotes" and "the official answer" are two very useful hints but not the ultimate truth.

Of course, it is reflecting on person's reputation if he/she accepts bad answers as "officially correct". Here I mean not the reputation number - but the reputation in people's mind. So, Olga please continue selecting answers with thoroughness as you do. :-)

It would be too easy if in programmer's SO we could always prove the correct answers. In many cases people ask "what is the best way of doing such-and-such thing" and this "best way" includes aesthetic feeling of software architecture. In 5% of cases to my mind the person who asks chooses not the best answer. (But I, too, may be mistaken). Sorting on SE sites by community upvotes helps a lot. Usually it is enough to read 2 or 3 top-voted answers to find an acceptable for me solution.